# Ajax form submit key up or change

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am creating a form without a submit button that will send a submission every time a form element changes value. (All text inputs)

If I use `onchange` event the form won't submit until I `blur` the field, which would be too late. I need it to submit on each minor change.  E.g. typing "five" would mean 5 submits.

If i use key up it will make a lot of submissions and create a race condition on the server. What is the best method of doing this? Are there any other options?

Comment: So you want to send ajax submit requests on every input change to the server without sending too many submissions? I don't see why you would want to do that in the first place.

Comment: Why would you want to submit the form (with many inputs) each time any input changes? If you can provide a reason, we may come up with a hack!

Comment: if you are trying to track every single little change (i.e. keypress) then you could have a key based handler cache those changes and have it submit every X milliseconds or so.  You can wrap your request with an interval timer.  Perhaps even have a handler on blur that trumps the interval and does a full submit.  By the way if you wrap your requests in a reasonable interval then if the timer is a reasonable length then your fears of a race condition are greatly allays as the timer has a more linear timer queue than ajax requests do.

Comment: The idea is, I will have a page of 25 forms that update data for a particular item. I don't want the user to remember to hit submit each time and I don't want a page refresh. I want behavior similar to google docs

Answer (score 0):

google docs uses a timer, saves every 2 seconds or so. http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/43174272622/auto-save-in-your-web-application

Other approaches to autosave exist, for example:

- a PUSH service [How does Google Docs autosave work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126128/how-does-google-docs-autosave-work)
- Using a javascript MV* framework. only changed data is synched http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/10/30/auto-save-your-model-in-angular-js-with-watch-and-debounce/

Comment: If I have a timer on let's say 20 forms, this could be a lot of requests at once. Do you think I should keep a list of the forms that actually have been edited and sync these only every 2 seconds? I don't want to do a push service

Comment: You would save all forms at once, so once every 2s total. You can do a client side check to see which fields have changed and then save only those fields.

Comment: Wouldn't 25 ajax requests be a lot for the server to handle?

Comment: your right, that idea aout keeping a list of changed forms should help